# ¿Como comparar un set en Java sin Hashcode?

Tags: java, set, conjuntos

Tengo una variable tal que:

`private set conjunto= new Hashset<int[]>();`

Y  hago lo siguiente:

```
Private void asignar(int elemento1, elemento2){

myArray={elemento1,elemento2}

conjunto.add(myArray)
}


Private Boolean funcion (int elemento1, int elemento2){
myArray={elemento1,elemento2}
return conjunto.contains(myArray);

}
```

Mi problema está en que la función está comparando los espacios de memoria #numero. Por lo que, aunque contenga el array los mismos elementos, siempre me devuelve false. ¿Existe alguna manera de solventar este fallo? Podría utilizar un Mapa y dejarme de tonterías, pero me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera en Java de que los Set en Java comparen como tal el elemento y no su espacio de memoria.

Gracias.

Comment: Has probado con [`Arrays.equals`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_equals_object.htm)?

Comment: Pero como podría hacerlo si el array que quiero comparar se encuentra dentro de un set

Comment: debes definir de la siguiente manera `Set<int[]> conjunto= new HashSet<int[]>();` para que no interprete los valores como `Object[]` , y luego podes hacer uso de lo que te indica Marc.. `boolean contains = conjunto.stream().anyMatch(c -> Arrays.equals(c, b));`

Comment: Recorrer el set probablemente sea un proceso muy lento cuando hay muchos datos. Además, pierde el proposito, por que podrías agregar dos arrays iguales por que tienen distinto hashcode.